# Need help calculating average from text file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, average

I've kind of run into a brick wall with one of my latest assignments where I have to calculate the class average from a text file that is created after a certain amount of inputs from a user.

Code:

```
 f=open('class.txt','w')

title=['name','english','math','science']
f.write(str(title)+""+"\n")


name=input("enter student name:")
m=int(input("enter math score:"))
e=int(input("enter english score:"))
s=int(input("enter science score:"))
o=input("do you wish to continue?: y/n:")
f.write(name + " " +str(m)+ " "+str(e)+" "+str(s)+" "+"\n")

name =[]
while o !='n':
    name=input("enter a student name:")
    m=int(input("enter math score:"))
    e=int(input("enter english score:"))
    s=int(input("enter science score:"))
    o=input("do you wish to continue?: y/n:")
    f.write(name + " " +str(m)+ " "+str(e)+" "+str(s)+" "+"\n")
f.close()
```

Basically, the text file needs a header, hence the line with "title" in it, and after the user hits 'n' the text file gets saved.

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the code that reads the text file, calculates the total score of each, calculates the average score of each student and then prints it all into three columns. If I could get any pointers as to how I should go about doing this it would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you write the code to produce the text file or is that given as part of the assignment?

Comment: The text file is not given as part of the assignment

Comment: Who wrote the code in your question?

Comment: I wrote it, it's the first part of the assignment.

Comment: Right - see answer below, do both parts with one run through. No need to read file back in again.

Comment: Right I understand that it is more efficient to do in the way that you described, but the assignment says that we have to read the file back again and calculate the average from that rather than taking it straight from the initial input.

Comment: OK - see the answer anyway about improving the loop, variable naming and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

*(I am not a phython programmer so the syntax may not be exactly right)*

I am assuming that you are to write the code that produces the text file and calculates the average at the same time. If so then no need write file then re-read it, just keep running total and calculate average when you're done.

```
numberOfStudents = 0
int totalMathScore = 0
# Only showing math score add lines to do same with english / science
# see below about how loop should be structured
while continue != 'n':
   numberOfStudents += 1
   m=int(input("enter math score:"))
   totalMathScore += m

# Now calculate average math score
averageMathScore = totalMathScore / numberOfStudents
```

---

Look for bits of repeated code and refactor. e.g. where you're getting the scores both outside and inside the loop. Thats poor style and should be either

a) Put that in a function

b) Or more likely for this simple example change loop to something like

```
continue = 'y'
while (continue != 'n'):
    name=input("enter a student name:")
    m=int(input("enter math score:"))
    e=int(input("enter english score:"))
    ...
```

---

Other bonuses

- Use descriptive variable names - e.g. mathScore rather than m
- Error handling - what happens if someone types in "BANANA" for a score?